# WordPress Big data handling tools

Tags: wordpress, elementor, formidable, xenocode

I have a CVS that contains 50k rows and 75 Col. I looking for tool or plugin for webpress which can show data dynamically. Have ajax filter and size of data shouldn't effect reponse time of website.

- It should be capable of integrating with CSV files without limitations on file size.
- It should include pre-defined AJAX filters with conditional dynamic dropdowns/lookups, a search bar, etc.
- The template should support grid and list views dynamically populated from the database.
- It should include a Reviews addon.
- A form builder feature is essential.
- Ideally, we are looking for a dynamic template for Elementor with all the necessary plugins integrated, based on our use case. If this tool supports integration with Firebase, it would significantly improve our website's response time.

I'm looking for any template with built-In functionality. So I don't have to code.